# Save Excel Sheet as HTML with Current Date

Tags: date, excel, save-as, vba

I am looking to set up a macro to save 6 different worksheets as individual HTML files daily with the current date.  I can find the code for saving as current date, and code for saving as HTML, I cannot figure out how to make them work together.  My first of the 6 sheets is named Admin.  Thank you for any help you can give me learning this one.

Here is the code I am currently trying and get errors with:

```
Sub SaveAsHTML()
'
' SaveAsHTML Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
  Dim newFile As String, fName As String
    fName = Range("A1").Value
    newFile = fName & " " & Format$(Date, "mmddyy") & ".htm"
    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObject.Add(xlSourcePrintArea, _
        "J:\Service Technology\Daily Stats\CSC Daily Report\Archive\Admin\fname" _
        , "Admin", "", xlHtmlStatic, "CSCDailyReport_29344", "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`fName` needs to be concatenated to the end of the path and `PublishObject` should be `PublishObjects`:

```
...
    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourcePrintArea, _
    "J:\Service Technology\Daily Stats\CSC Daily Report\Archive\Admin\" & fName _
...
```

Comment: I made that change.  I am getting a Run_Time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method.  it highlights the "J:\Service Technology\Daily Stats\CSC Daily Report\Archive\Admin\" & fName _
        , "Admin", "", xlHtmlStatic, "CSCDailyReport_29344", "") section.

Comment: @Rich Answer revised, `PublishObjects` is the collection that you are using the `Add` method of.